# Growing Ui controls when put in to a bigger screen

Tags: gui-design, human-interface-guideline

I am working on an desktop application where i have some limited no of controls.I have a doubt that whether when I run my application in bigger screen shall i grow the controls or centered all the controls or left aligned the controls.What ui guidelines says for this?Any suggestion on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much information in your question, so my answer might be vague, or my assumptions incorrect, but let's try...

Assuming the app has a standard set of "controls" (labels, text input, spinners, radio and check boxes), not much will be gained by enlarging them. For example, you should not enlarge the font size with the window size. Your user will have set a font size they are comfortable with. (If you had charts or other custom controls, enlarging might allow displaying more/other data, making it more useful. Tell us about the controls and their data if you have such.)

I'm assuming the app runs on a desktop, and the "bigger screen" results in either the user resizing the app window, or the user having a better resolution than you anticipated. I also assume there is no additional information the app can display.

So if the controls stay fixed size, and the number of controls stays stable, the only thing you can change is the layout. [Letterboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_%28filming%29) is one possibility, although in this context it's not adding black bars on top and bottom, but rather on the left and right sides. You might also increase some column paddings, to make the content more spacious. Do not increase all whitespace uniformly, though; increase padding between semantic units (such as main content and sidebar), because that helps recognize the structure of the page.

You might also think about what happens when the user tries to reduce the window size: Often, programs will not allow to shrink the window below a certain size (because that would require scrolling, hiding information). Maybe a maximum window size is appropriate in your case?